# Cannot style a hover event on a circle

Tags: css, svg

In my DOM, I have:

```
<g transform="translate(0,200)" id="annotations">
  <g class="annotation">
    <circle r="10" cx="150" cy="50" style="opacity: 1;">
    </circle>
  </g>
  <g class="annotation">
    <circle r="10" cx="100" cy="10" style="opacity: 1;">
    </circle>
  </g>
</g>
```

In my css I have:

```
 #annotations circle {
         fill: rgb(255,0,0);
 }
 #annotations circle:hover {
         fill: rgb(0,0,0);
 }
```

The circles are correctly displayed in red, but the `:hover` pseudoclass does not work. In fact, the style declaration doesn't even show up in Chrome dev tools. When I change the former declaration without the pseudoclass into one with a pseudoclass in the dev tools, the declaration is greyed out (invalid). What is wrong here? I thought one can style svg elemens like this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jfM4b/ Code is working fine.

Comment: code is working fine http://editor.livegap.com/?tid=uy8gd99sow899

Comment: Found out that the g#annotations element is overlaid by a transparent image element - the circles were still visible, but practically, they were "non-detectable" by the mouse. May be closed.

Comment: The answer is trivial and not directly related to the question.